# Google Chromeの印刷設定（両面）の制御について

Tags: windows, google-chrome

#### 問題の要約

Google Chromeの印刷機能を開くたびに片面印刷がデフォルトで表示される方法はあるでしょうか？

#### 事象

Windows 10のGoogle Chromeで毎回、印刷設定で変更した値を次回開くときに備えて覚えているのではないかと思える挙動をしています。
そこで、毎回、印刷設定をデフォルト値に戻す方法はあるか調査をしております。

具体的には、初回は印刷設定で「両面」にチェックが入っており、チェックを外してから、印刷もしくはキャンセルすると次回、印刷設定を開く時に、前回変更した設定値のまま表示されます。
上記を何らかの方法で制御を掛けたいと考えております。

#### 試したこと

レジストリで設定項目があるのでは思い、全ての項目は見ていないのですが、printを検索キーとして調べたところ

[PrintingDuplexDefault](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#PrintingDuplexDefault)

> このポリシーでは、デフォルトの両面印刷モードをオーバーライドできます。このモードを使用できない場合、このポリシーは無視されます。

で初期値を上書きできました。

しかし、Chromeの印刷設定を変更すると、次回印刷設定を開いた時には、変更したままになっていたので解決しませんでした。恐らく「記憶」に関する項目があるのではないかと仮説を立てて、historyなどのキーワードで検索を掛けましたが
それらしい項目の機能は見当たりませんでした。

#### 代替案

[DisablePrintPreview](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DisablePrintPreview)

> このポリシーを有効に設定した場合、Google Chrome ではユーザーが印刷をリクエストしたときに組み込みの印刷プレビューではなくシステムの印刷ダイアログが開きます。このポリシーを無効に設定するか未設定のままにした場合、印刷コマンドを実行すると印刷プレビュー画面が表示されます。

を使用しようかと思います。毎回、「システムの印刷ダイアログ」をマウスで押すのは面倒臭いため。
欠点は、chrome上で印刷プレビューが出ませんが、印刷機側（driver設定）で確か、印刷する前にプレビューする設定があったのではないかと考えています。（未検証）

#### 関連するコード

特になし
※もしコードを書かないと解決しないようでしたら、その旨もご教示ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。